# CoreData: should I use binary store for little data(less than 1MB) to improve query speed?

Tags: ios, core-data

My iOS app requires little local data, average user won't user more than 1 MB, but it does many queries(fetches) with predicate, so I'm thinking loading the whole sqlite file into memory when I launch to improve query speed, but I didn't see a way to do that.
So I'm thinking using NSBinaryStoreType, while will be loaded into memory when app launches, and queries much faster, am I doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user465191,

Rather than speculate on the performance differences, perhaps you should just try both types? It is extremely easy to create and use both store types.

In reality, every app has a working set. Core Data's managed object contexts and store coordinators (and, I add, SQLite itself) are quite good at caching information. I doubt you will see little difference on a database of your size.

As in all engineering endeavors, use data to guide your hand. Your app is different than mine. I would love to know the results of your comparison. Your mileage will vary.

Andrew

Comment: I tested it, with a very small database(200K by sqlite and 400K by binary, binary queries uses half time of sqlite, but writing binary store cost more than twice the time of sqlite store, so considering extensibility, I choose sqlite. I think I misunderstood the point binary stresses, I choose it since it is totally In-memory, but In-memory isn't the main feature of a binary store, its atomic right?

Comment: Dwayne, There are many reasons to choose the binary store. That said, I almost always choose the SQLite store. Saving the binary store is a large write operation, which is generally quite efficient but redundantly writes unchanged records. With the new concurrent queue MOCs, I am finding little advantage to the binary store. Your mileage will vary. Andrew

Comment: would you like to recommend some material on the topic of binary store? I'm not quite sure what a binary store is good at.

Comment: Dwayne, I don't know of any good resources here. By and large, the binary store is used for things that primarily exist in memory and are rarely persisted. IOW, you use it when you need to run faster than SQLite's caching strategies allow. I've rarely stuck with the decision to use the binary store and have always reverted to the SQLite store. Andrew